# At a/the __ level or At __level . Article or not? If yes which one (a or the)?

Tags: grammar, expressions, articles

I would like some help with the following expressions, as I see them used in different ways:

Actions to reduce pollution **at a/the municipal level** play a crucial role.

Actions to reduce pollution **at municipal level** play a crucial role.

---

Actions to reduce pollution **at a/the international level** play a crucial role.

Actions to reduce pollution **at international level** play a crucial role.

---

Actions to reduce pollution **at a/the local level** play a crucial role.

Actions to reduce pollution **at local level** play a crucial role.

---

Actions to reduce pollution **at a/the sector level** play a crucial role.

Actions to reduce pollution **at sector level** play a crucial role.

---

My question is about using the article "a/the" or not when it comes to sentences of this kind, is there a rule or it depends on the word preceding "level"?

If yes which one (a or the)?

Thank you

Comment: I'd usually use 'the'.

Comment: Thank you Edwin. Do you think that the other forms are incorrect or it is possible to use both?

Comment: I'd stick with 'the', but not be appalled by any examples containing 'a'. Modern usage may be seeing an upsurge in the anarthous versions, but 'at local level' is perhaps a couple of decades away from being favoured. I'm not familiar with any of the 'sector' examples (living in the UK), so 'at sector level' sounds at least as good as the others to me. Like something I'd read in a space opera.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples, I would use "the". But in other cases I might use no or the indefinite article, for example,

> It was a smoggy day. Pollution made the air at ground level almost unbreathable.
>
> It's an understatement to say that Labron James plays basketball at a high level.

It depends on whether the adjective you're using is chosen from an implied set, in which case you're specifying a particular level from some set of levels the audience knows about, and the definite article is appropriate. Or if the adjective is simply descriptive, in which case no article or the indefinite is appropriate.